# Why are my drop-out values NOT affecting the accuracy in my recurrent neural model? (IMDB dataset, TFLearn)

Tags: neural-networks, python, tensorflow

1. So in the code below, which is pretty standard LSTM training for the IMDB dataset, I have run extensive experiments where I changed the drop-out value from 0.5 all the way up to 1, and the accuracy on the test set is ALWAYS ~78%, never deviating by that very much. I even tried extremely low drop-out values, such as 0.2 and 0.1, and got the exact same result. Does anyone know why the accuracy of the trained model seems impervious to the drop-out rate?
2. Going along with the same code, I then happened to tweak a few parameters: changed the learning rate from 0.001 to 0.005, and the batch size from 32 to 25, and NOW the drop-out values do have a large impact on the accuracy of the trained model. Again, why is that?

```
from __future__ import division, 
print_function, absolute_import

import tflearn
from tflearn.data_utils import to_categorical, pad_sequences
from tflearn.datasets import imdb

# IMDB Dataset loading
train, valid, test = imdb.load_data(
    path='imdb.pkl', n_words=10000, valid_portion=0.1)
trainX, trainY = train
testX, testY = test
validX, validY = valid

# Data preprocessing
# Sequence padding
trainX = pad_sequences(trainX, maxlen=100, value=0.)
validX = pad_sequences(validX, maxlen=100, value=0.)
testX = pad_sequences(testX, maxlen=100, value=0.)

# Converting labels to binary vectors
trainY = to_categorical(trainY, nb_classes=2)
validY = to_categorical(validY, nb_classes=2)
testY = to_categorical(testY, nb_classes=2)

# Network building
net = tflearn.input_data([None, 100])
net = tflearn.embedding(net, input_dim=10000, output_dim=128)
net = tflearn.lstm(net, 128, dropout=0.1)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 2, activation='softmax')
net = tflearn.regression(
    net, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=0.001,
    loss='categorical_crossentropy')

# Training
model = tflearn.DNN(net, tensorboard_verbose=0)
model.fit(trainX, trainY, n_epoch = 3,
          validation_set=(validX, validY), show_metric=True, 
          batch_size=32)

score = model.evaluate(testX, testY)
print('Test accuracy: %0.4f%%' % (score[0] * 100))
```

Comment: Can you try to do learning rate .001 but batch size of 25. Since you've changed both it is difficult to say what caused the net to change. Most likely it just doesn't train at all for some reason